# Which collection should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, collections

I'm looking for the ideal collection to use in my current situation.

All I need is a `List<string>` which can allow **two** entries for each index.  Similar to a `Dictionary`, however I do not need keys and values, and would like to iterate through it by index.  The best collection I can think of is a multi-dimension array, however I would like to specify that two items can be stored in each element, however the amount of elements can be infinite.

Which collection should I use?

**EDIT**: Also, I thought of using a `List<List<string>>`, however since I only need two elements for each index, I think storing a list in each index position of the list would be a waste.

Comment: If you are using this to iterate by index then Tuple is fine.  If you are to use this in a HashSet Tuple is not a good candidate as it generates a lot of hash collisions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Tuple`

Check this: [Tuple (Class)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

```
var population = new Tuple<string, string>("New York", "Madrid");
```

Comment: I had never heard of this collection. Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: If you want named members instead of `Item1`, `Item2`, and so on, use a custom class.

Comment: @bechm see the answer by John Kenedy

Comment: Just keep in mind that Tuple was only introduced in more recent versions of the framework

Comment: It's easier to use the static helper method like this: `var population = Tuple.Create("New York", "Madrid");` because with a method you won't have to specify the generic parameters `<string, string>` because they can be inferred. With a new-object expression, you have to give the generic parameters, like above.

Comment: But note that `Tuple<>` and `Tuple<,>` (1-tuples and 2-tuples) are different classes, so they don't easily fit into the same `List<>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try use a class

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Data1 {get;set;}
    public string Data2 {get;set;}
}

var obj = List<MyData>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tuple with a helper method which is more straightforward

```
var population = Tuple.Create("New York", "Madrid")
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also try with the jagged array (array of arrays):

```
 object[] row1 = new object[2]; // create a one dimensional array
 for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
 {
     row1[i] = "yourValues "+i; // push your values into the array
 }

 object[,] multi=new object[1,2];
            multi[0,0] = row1; // push the created array into 2dimensional array

for (int j = 0; j < ((object[])(multi[0, 0])).Length; j++)
                MessageBox.show(((object[])(row[0, 0]))[j]); // retrieve value from
```

the multidimensional array with index.

Thanks.